# JavaFX Binding String to TreeCell Factory Properly

Tags: java, javafx

I'm getting an issue, where when I expand and unexpand a tree cell. The text I binded to doesn't ever go away.. What could be the cause of this?

This is what I get
[image]

Here is my code

```
        treeView.setCellFactory(t -> {

                return new TreeCell<Entry>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Entry entry, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(entry, empty);

                        if (entry != null) {

                            if (empty) {
                                setText(null);
                                setGraphic(null);
                            } else {

                                if (entry.getImage() != null) {

                                    Image image = FXUtils.toFXImage(entry.getImage());

                                    setGraphic(new ImageView(image));

                                } else {
                                    setGraphic(null);
                                }

                                textProperty().bind(entry.nameProperty());

                            }


                        }

                    }

                };

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a cell is empty, the item is also `null`. However all your logic is only executed, if `(entry != null)`, i.e. never, if the cell is empty or the item is `null`. Furthermore this should fail, even if you fix this error, since you never unbind the `textProperty`, but it could be set for empty cells. Change your `updateItem` method to something like this:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Entry entry, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(entry, empty);

    textProperty().unbind();

    if (empty || entry == null) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        if (entry.getImage() != null) {
            Image image = FXUtils.toFXImage(entry.getImage());
            setGraphic(new ImageView(image));
        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        textProperty().bind(entry.nameProperty());
    }

}
```